# Installing LyX: "No textclass is found."

Tags: lyx

[About installing LyX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482526/about-installing-lyx?noredirect=1#comment1222768_482526)

This is my old post.

---

I have been trying to install LyX, but the same error message pops out when I excute LyX.exe as follows:

> LyX: No textclass is found
>
> LyX will only have minimal functionality because no textclasses have been found. You can either try to reconfigure LyX normally, try to reconfigure without checking your LaTeX installation, or continue.
>
> (Press the button) Reconfigure (or) Without LaTeX (or) Continue

---

Before LyX, I used TeXLive as my tex distribution, and I'm using Windows 10.

Here's what I have done to fix the problem in a chronological order:

1. I installed LyX, and it did not work. I followed the instructions given in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kALm051M0iA&t=179s
2. I thought TeXLive was not okay as a tex program for LyX, so I installed MikTex 2.9.
3. In the old post, a commenter corrected me to use only one tex distributions for LyX, and recommended me to delete all of the three programs, and do it again.
4. I did it so, and I installed TeXLive(this is because I'm used to it) and LyX, and with the same error message.
5. http://www.ktug.org/xe/index.php?mid=KTUG_open_board&document_srl=174234
   This link suggests to replace the "configure.py" file by new one attached in the link, and I did it, but the same result.
6. As a commenter says, I emailed to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org to ask for advice, and one user answers very kindly, and the following are his suggestions and the corresponding results.
7. I opened a Command Prompt (Start Menu -> cmd.exe) and type "where pdflatex." The result was

"C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe",

where the installation program of LyX chose as a path to latex.exe.

7. I "reconfigured" LyX (Tools -> Reconfigure), then LyX says

> The system reconfiguration has failed. Default textclass is used but LyX may not be able to work properly. Please reconfigure again if needed.

I still have the message after I restart LyX.

8. Now, I tried the suggestions in the link:

[LyX installation error- text class not found- 'Reconfigure' or 'use without latex' option coming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280731/lyx-installation-error-text-class-not-found-reconfigure-or-use-without-late)

8.1) opened a command prompt in windows with administrative privileges.

8.2) navigated to the directory containing lyx.exe 'c:\program files (x86)\lyx 2.1\bin' on my machine.

8.3) executed lyx.exe

8.4) everything involving python calls failed - reconfigure (which uses configure.py), opening old documents (which uses lyx2lyx), etc.

8.5) exited lyx back to the command prompt

8.6) on the command line typed 'set pythonpath=' which clears the pythonpath.

8.7) on the command line typed 'set path=' which clears the path.

8.8) typed lyx.exe to reenter lyx

8.9) but the result was the same, sad.

9. Now, second try: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Troubleshooting

9.1)Uninstall LyX from your PC if you have used an installation folder whose name exists of seperate words like C:\Program Files.

9.2)Reinstall LyX and consider, that you use a folder whose name exists of just one word like C:\Lyx15

9.3)Start the Command Prompt in windows (Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Command Prompt)

9.4)Change directory to C:\ (type c:)

9.5)Type "c:/lyx15/python/python.exe c:/lyx15/resources/configure.py" in the Command Prompt and press "return"

9.6)After the configuration has been finished you will find 4 files in the directory c:\ -> configure.log, lyxrc.defaults, textclass.lst and packages.lst. The browser could find the first two files, but not the latter two files. I kept going. (Maybe problems with lst format?)

9.7)Cut these 4 files and paste them into the \Username\Application Data\LyX folder. If a directory for Lyx does not exist create a new one.

9.8)Start Lyx.

But, to no avail.

10) I again deleted TeXLive, Lyx, and installed MikTex2.9, LyX.
I did the above, but no improvement.

11) One comment in the old post suggests to the following:

Since you changed configuration to MiKTeX it may help to go back to basics. LyX looks for TeX at start-up & should reconfigure itself to suit so important we know how well set MiKTeX is. From any point on your system get cmd prompt type in> pdfLaTeX --version you should get a response of numbers confirming that LyX can do similar. If that step says like not an operable command then LyX wont know how to proceed. Also enter> Where /r \ pdfLaTeX which should confirm how many copies may be conflicting (check that it matches> Where $path:pdflatex ) the two should agree on one single copy.

12) Now, any suggestions would be appreciated. I came to the point that I don't understand why I'm doing it so hard.

---

Updates.

I reinstalled Miktex and LyX in the C file to rule out any Korean characters and spaces in their addresses.

Here is the result:

[image]

The first two lines show that the two commands "where /r \ pdflatex" and "where $path:latex" give different results. The Korean in the second answer is:

정보: 제공된 패턴에 해당되는 파일을 찾지 못했습니다

==Information: no files corresponding to the given pattern is found.

Second, I typed "c:\lyx2.3\python\python.exe c:\lyx2.3\resources\configure.py," but the error "Remission denied: c:\configure.log," and there was no textclass in the last line.

I focused on any involvement in Korean characters and spaces, and did the same tests, I am not sure I've done right as the answer guides.

---

Updates.

The two "where" matches:

> C:\Users\장지웅>where /r \ pdflatex
>
> C:\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe
>
> C:\Users\장지웅>where $path:pdflatex
>
> C:\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe.

Being aware of the changed directory name "LyX2.3," I did the action "c:\lyx15\python\python.exe c:\lyx15\resources\configure.py" with lyx15 replaced by lyx2.3. The result takes some time, which was new to me, but the two latter files of configure.log, lyxrc.defaults, textclass.lst and packages.lst are not found.

---

Updates.

Here's the path.

C:\Users\장지웅>PATH

PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cuminas\Document Express DjVu Plug-in\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Programs\Matlab\bin;C:\Lyx2.3\Perl\bin;C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\

---

Updates.

Progress! Now no message that no textclass is found.

What I did first is to cut and paste textclass.lst and other files (from the past installation, I think) in the folder here and there. For example,

C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Roaming
C:\Lyx2.3\Resources
C:\Windows\Application Data
C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Roaming

(장지웅 is my name.)

Then the shortcut in Desktop opens with no error message, the View (ctrl+R) button was not available, even though I opened newfile.

[image]

Second, I followed the instruction:

Traditionally it was easy to modify the start up icon however with windows 10 it is a bit more convoluted. So in the start menu find Lyx right click the LyX icon follow More to Open File Location which should take you to the user folder ....\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\LyX 2.3 now again right click the small LyX icon and select properties and you should see "Target" box has C:\LyX2.3\bin\LyX.exe this is where you need to paste the amended command e.g. C:\Lyx2.3\Lyx.exe -userdir C:\Lyx2.3\UserDir

There was a change. When I tried to open a newfile, the following message came up;

[image]

Then, I could press the View button, but LyX said

[image]

and in turn

[image]

After this message poped up, the Lyx ended automatically.

Third, I opened a new notepad and typed "C:\LyX2.3\UserDir" and saved it as startLyX.cmd on the desktop.

Fourth, I created a Temp folder at C:\Lyx2.3, and set the temporary directory as suggested, I could not see any change.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it now work?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Nope...

Comment: OK that last part shows latex is ok (however it is on a path with Korean ? characters that is most likely part of the issue) so we need to get lyx to see it using the troubleshooting suggestion again run (with back slashes as I have here `c:\lyx15\python\python.exe c:\lyx15\resources\configure.py` (this may again be part of the issue since \ gets converted) it should take several minutes streaming the locations it finds and if you don't get the 4 files it failed so we may need to consider a fresh approach

Comment: @KJO I reposted the result as a new answer(is there any appropriate way to reply to your answer, not as a comment?). Hmm... no progress. Please take a look.

Comment: @KJO I added the new result.

Comment: So now the MiKTeX values are in sync what does your current path look like and if you start MiKTeX-console can you check it behaves as expected I suggest go to the settings page and check the directories tab

Comment: @KJO What do you mean by my current path? and MiKTeX says that MiKTeX Console cannot be started. I guess this is a problem, isn't it?

Comment: your sytem path is the route the applications traverse to locate each other hence we are trying to ensure the critical binaries are found in a known location the way to show it from a console prompt is to simply enter PATH to see the resultant list. and yes if MiKTeX-console is not running then it could be highlighting some weakness in the configuration

Comment: @KJO I added the path.

Comment: If you decide to change to TexLive first remove all traces of MiKTeX installation For install-TL-windows.exe see https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html I suggest DONT run as admin use single-user install second option Custom install Continue (NOT admin) Change PORTABLE setup to YES this is important since it potentially avoids the appdata user issues

Comment: @KJO Yes, I deleted MikTeX and installed TL with the option Custom install and PORTABLE checked YES. But, LyX couldn't find the path of latex.exe. I wrote c:\texlive\2018\bin\win32 as a try, but it does not work.

Comment: I know its frustrating Its back to passing the same initial test> Where /r \latex and Where $path:latex MUST agree then ignoring \latex.exe it should be one from each is what lyx effectively tests it looks in the path for latex and others to build a list of supported formats from the one location it will build its list in the userdir which is why we need to tell it that we want a `-userdir` in its own folders system (the area where it should have no problems with) I can not see any reason why it is misbehaving if those are plain latin characters, unless some other process is interfering

Comment: @KJO The result of the two where test:
c:\>where /r \ latex
c:\TeXLive\2018\bin\win32\latex.exe

c:\>where $path:latex
정보: 제공된 패턴에 해당되는 파일을 찾지 못했습니다.
(Information: no files corresponding to the given pattern is found.)

They do not match.

Comment: In summary we are trying to ensure lyx does not attempt to use your `C:\Users\장지웅\AppData` or any other folder that is located in `C:\Users\장지웅` such as "Documents" since LyX cannot handle those "glyphs" (see your recent error message ref documents folder) For that reason you need a work/document folder that is outside that area. In my screen shots you may see I have a folder called `C:\Lyx2.3\work` but it can be anywhere just NOT in your user area, e.g. it could be `c:\MyLyxDocs` this is a work around for problems that LyX & other parts of TeX cannot see those glyphs as a valid path name.

Comment: The reason I suggested that LyX is configured to use its own `c:\lyx2.3\temp` folder (which it builds and often empties/deletes during each session) is to avoid it using the `C:\Users\장지웅\AppData\Local\Temp` folder and it may help if other TeX componets are also told to do likewise so in startLyx.cmd we could add two lines before the line that calls LyX so line 1 would be `set tmp=c:\lyx2.3\temp` and line 2 should be `set temp=c:\lyx2.3\temp` then when/IF LyX asks other parts of TeX to work with files in progress for that session they are all working in the same temporary folder.

Answer (score 1):

On this occasion **This answer did not work for the OP** (Original Post), I am leaving it here since It may help other users that have a similar problem with running a portable install on an affected system.

One of the problems with many interdependent programs is that when chained together it only needs one to have a problem with file paths including spaces or extended characters then many downstream applications can fail.

Many users find that LyX or more likely its dependency on Python, Perl, Synctex etc.
Can lead to such issues.

In the following drive: can be any including the `C:` drive

The solution is to install portable LyX in its own folder such as `drive:\lyx2.3` (current version is 2.32-2)
Equally if MiKTeX or Tex Live components are causing issues  (use only one) it may help to use the Portable version and install to `drive:\miktex2.9` (current version is 2.9.7) or `drive:\texlive\2019` (presuming it is released this month).

If you get the message from LyX : unable to find textclass file then the python component was unable to work correctly during install possibly as a result of a path naming issue.

**The first test is to check that there is only one pdfLaTeX and that it is included in the path variable so from a command prompt run**

```
>  where /r drive:\ pdfLaTeX
>  where $path:pdflatex
```

both should agree it will of course vary for each user HOWEVER it should be one IDENTICAL entry for both commands

> e.g. c:\ ..tex.. \ .. \some\bin\pdflatex.exe

**We now have two options when running LyX and in some cases changing the UserDir may be the better one.** see **UserDir** below.

The traditional fix i.e. to build the files that failed during installation run (replacing Lyx## with whatever you used for your install)

```
drive:\lyx##\python\python.exe drive:\lyx##\resources\configure.py
```

There should be lots of activity as it rebuild the long list of interdependent files it finds and at the end you may have as many as 13 new files in the folder you ran it.
IMPORTANT one should be the **textclass.lst** we are needing to clear the error.

These files need to be placed in your user installation folder which by default will be hidden so the simplest way to find it is enter into an explorer address bar

```
 %appdata%
```

and look for a folder such as `LyX2.3` (the current default) this is where the 13 files need to be placed.

If that does not work for you then an alternative is to use

### **UserDir**

When you start LyX you can specify a user directory other than the default one (which is hidden in user appdata). If using a batch file then you could use an alternative set=*userdir* variable but I am not adding it here as it varies over time, read the current customisation.pdf section *Your local configuration directory* for the current environment variable.

This may be useful when a user name has spaces or unexpected characters.
So given that you have installed Lyx in a Directory such as c:\Lyx2.3 you would need to change the startup shortcut to add a foldername so the command you use to start LyX becomes

```
C:\Lyx2.3\bin\Lyx.exe -userdir C:\Lyx2.3\UserDir
```

On first run LyX should ask if you want it to build the directory and after some delay you will find the user configuration files have been added including **textclass.lst**. you can confirm the directory changed by looking at "help" "about"

[image]

The simplest way to start LyX with this parameter is to cut and paste the line above into a text file on the desktop then ensure you rename the file with a .cmd or .bat filename such as startLyX.cmd (ensure it is NOT.cmd.txt or else it will simply open in the editor instead of running LyX). Now you can double click that file so that it runs LyX with the extra directive.

Traditionally it was easy to modify the start up icon however with windows 10 it is a bit more convoluted. So in the start menu find Lyx right click the LyX icon follow More to Open File Location which should take you to the user  folder ....\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\LyX 2.3 now again right click the small LyX icon and select properties and you should see "Target" box has C:\LyX2.3\bin\LyX.exe this is where you need to paste the amended command e.g. `C:\Lyx2.3\bin\Lyx.exe -userdir C:\Lyx2.3\UserDir`

In order to ensure LyX is not using remote problematic directories for working it is desirable to also set its temporary directory to the same area so under preferences paths navigate to LyX main folder and add a new folder called Temp (or whatever but keep it simple latin characters) now LyX should not have any reason to use appdata folders.

[image]

**Once LyX is happy to run then you need to `CHECK TEX` `scan`,  `reconfigure` & `restart`**

[image]

Comment: It would be better to add a comment here. I found the file textclass.lst and the other files. I guess by the time when the files were created that they are from the use of UserDir. They are now located at C:\Users\장지웅.

Comment: In combination with my comment above we are now trying to avoid the c:\users area and tell lyx to work with the portable tex live in a "userdir" of its own making like in the example above thus you need lyx to confirm on its "help" "about lyx" "user directory =" entry that it is c:\Lyx.2.3\UserDir  NOT as previous in ~appdata\

Comment: Yes, I now see that "User directory: ~\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3\" in the "help" "about lyx" is problematic. How can I change this to c:\Lyx.2.3\UserDir?

Comment: I added the new result. I have questions. I wonder why the two "where" tests does not agree. Is it not important now? and where do I save the startLyX.cmd file?

Comment: The desktop file should have 1 line with 3 parts `C:\Lyx2.3\bin\Lyx.exe -userdir C:\Lyx2.3\UserDir` and a double click will start LYX telling it to USE own USERDIR this is how we get LyX to NOT use your name. Unfortunate user directories such as "documents" "downloads" "pictures" on Win are accessed via username

Comment: Yes, the where's agree now. I'm not sure what the last comment means. I changed startLyX.txt to startLyX.cmd, and its content is exactly "C:\Lyx2.3\bin\Lyx.exe -userdir C:\Lyx2.3\UserDir." And then, I double clicked. I opened LyX and implemented CHECK TEX scan,  reconfigure & restart, but reconfigure failed.

Comment: What I did is to run LyX, tex information, rescan, and reconfigure for "one time exit" in your comment, to be sure. Reconfigure has failed, and then I deleted the UserDir folder, and clicked startLyX.cmd on the desktop, but this run says nothing; instead, some command prompt pops up for a very short momment. When I opened LyX again, a message says the UserDir is missed, and lets me choose Create directory or Exit LyX. I created directory, and the UserDir was created, but after then the same result. I rescanned tex information, and reconfigured, which has failed.

Comment: JJW I think there are just too many places LyX is holding and gathering information from such as the Registry that it will be best to change the method to suit. The portable approach should have worked and if built on another machine would in all probability have worked but the "foreign" to LyX  characters of your username seem to be the root of the problem. I have to suggest 1) uninstall LyX, and delete the Lyx2.3 folder 2) Add a NEW USER account using simple characters e.g. JJW then for the new user the path to TeX Live (where=where) must agree first 3) install LyX in  Lyx2.3 via JJW account

Comment: I have made a new account with name "JJW," and I deleted LyX in the original account (Should I change the order of the first two actions? I am just writing down exactly what I did). I installed LyX in the new account, in the folder C:\LyX2.3 with UserDir folder. To match the two where's, I edited paths in the Environment Variables, and worked. It was all okay, except that when I pressed the View button in a new Lyx file, LyX said that a pdf viewer is not found. So, I set Adobe Reader as a default pdf viewer. I pressed again the View button, and now no response.

Comment: Now the same message pops up as follows: Fatal error: Acrobat failed to connect to a DDE server.

Comment: Since you changed name you should not need the "userdir" approach LyX should now behave "normally" yes the viewer needs to be set correctly for the new account and Acrobat is one that LyX should understand but as you are now finding it brings its own issues. LyX for all its editor WYSIWYG  "simplicity" is a damn complicated beast designed by Linux users I don't use acrobat with LyX for several reasons to do with synctex, so it will take a while for me to "corrupt" my system to see the issues.

Comment: Yes, now I changed the default program to Sumatra PDF, which was introduced in the Youtube video that I watched to install LyX for the first time. I think now everything's done. The reason why I am trying to use LyX is that a professor who researches plasma physics suggested me to handle complicated computations, which means LyX is better than hand computations. Now I am gonna get used to it. By the way, is there any pdf viewer program that you recommend?

Comment: You got it I support SumatraPDF and it is the one used by Lyx Windows developers for inverse searching read https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF%20with%20LyX.pdf it is out of date as there is now a better way but for now follow that guide

Comment: Well I think we both learnt a lot about LyX but my answer now seems inappropriate I suggest we summarise with a fresh answer (I will trim the first one but with your permission leave 1st answer in place since it may help in other cases) I will trim out some ov the comments where they did not add anything new

Comment: Of course, you can modify the post as you like, it will enhance readability. I'll refer to the PDF and also I have to say that I appreciate your help. I'll use it well.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the possibilities of adjusting LyX's behaviour using a "portable" approach as given in the other answer, in this case the solution was to simply add a fresh username composed of simple characters.

NOTE a number of users may arrive here who have either accented names or be composed UTF-8 characters or simply have a two-part name with a space. In such cases it is best to consider adding a new user to the system with a single plain ascii moniker.

e.g.  `c:\users\me\`

IF you have already installed TeX and LyX you have likely encountered the issue of LyX complaining it cant find the TeX classes. So as a minimum **uninstall LyX for that problem account.**

Now using the new account BEFORE you do a fresh LyX install, first check that your TeX is correctly configured. On windows you need to confirm that the two following commands agree EXACTLY.

So to test all is well check that there is only one pdfLaTeX and that it is included in the path variable so from a command prompt run

```
>  where /r \ pdfLaTeX
>  where $path:pdflatex
```

both should agree it will of course vary for each user HOWEVER it should be one IDENTICAL entry for both commands

> e.g. c:\ ..tex.. \ .. \some\bin\pdflatex.exe

Using the fresh account next check if installing LyX clears the problem. If you still encounter issues with the underlying TeX (MiKTeX or Tex Live) then you may need to consider re-installing one of those again. But **again ensure** you pass the **where** test before starting the new LyX.

When you make significant changes to the underlying programs especially MiKTeX updates, you may need to frequently use the "Reconfigure" option within LyX.

An associated problem can be the choice of PDF viewer since LyX uses background processes such as DDE or Pipes to control the pdf viewing. You may wish to check out alternatives.