# How do I import latex files into LyX?

Tags: lyx, import

I am new to LyX and trying to import the Latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a Latex document.
\end{document}
```

I get the error

An error occurred while running tex2lyx2.3-f "TestLyx.tex" "TestLyx.lyx"

There was an earlier similar question that was solved by updating Lyx but I am using the latest version. This seems too simple for anything to go wrong but I must be doing something.

Answer (score 1):

Cant really make it more mwe than that
I presume the file above was saved as TestLyx.tex and not in an unusual folder path.

Presumably in a documents folder under your user name, and that user name does NOT have accents spaces or other non-latin characters)

Lyx needs to be installed correctly such that using the <kbd>tools</kbd> <kbd>check tex</kbd> it confirms all is well with TeX.

You selected `File` `Import` `LaTeX (plain)` and it should have shown as

[image]

The message as shown should be Importing .......tex2lyx -f "TextLyx.tex" "TextLyx.lyx"

NOTE you either have a typo or there is something drastically wrong since there should be a space between `tex2lyx` and `-f`

Use `view` `messages pane` to check there is a space if no space you need to consult Lyx support
Proceeding on the basis it's a typo within your question and there is a space, then why do you get
`An error occurred …`

The most likely culprits are
1) something bad in the tex file, unlikely but not impossible so ensure it is a very simple cut and past file (as I did with notepad)
2) file is on a bad path (please include such detail in your question)
3) tex2lyx is on a bad path
   go to a cmd prompt (use any means but **avoid** starting within the LyX folders) and run

> ```
> >where $path:tex2lyx
> >where /r \ tex2lyx
> ```

Confirm both are **exactly the same answer** especially **the path before** tex2lyx
Tell us what those paths are (just the once)

However I can tell you even after a week of trying [hangul characters may not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483668/installing-lyx-no-textclass-is-found) and had to resort to a fresh user account.

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing LyX solved the problem.

Comment: I guess you can thus pass the basic ""where"" tests to avoid any other related lyx path problems

Comment: Import is working but using the "where" commands gave me                                        C:\Users\jwrudn>where $path:tex2lyx                                                            
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)              
C:\Users\jwrudn>where /r \ tex2lyx
C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\tex2lyx.exe                                                   
Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: yes lyx has not been configured such that its binary folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\` is available to system users. Not a big deal if its working for you, however that folder may need to be added to the "system path" for associated apps to work with the contents